# How does the maxMessageCount work in service bus trigger?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

In the official document there is a binding that seems to control to number of message sent to the function when triggered at one time.
[image]

Let say maxMessageCount = 5, and there are 10 messages in the queue. Is it working like the first 5 messages trigger the function, and as soon as the function receive them, the next 5 trigger the second time? Or will the function wait for the first 5 messages to be completed, then to process the next 5 messages?

Another question:
Let say maxMessageCount = 5 and maxConcurrentCalls = 1. Is there any interval between each batch got processed?

Comment: maxConcurrentCalls tells the trigger to run multiple Service Bus readers.  These are independent and do not coordinate with one another.   There is no guarantee of an interval between concurrent calls.  Your mental model should be competing consumers running at the same time, each of which may invoke a different function instance or reuse an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

When invoked, this is the maximum number of messages the Function will receive in a batch. The function will continue to be triggered as long as messages are not locked (leased) and are active. If your function is configured for concurrent executions, it will get invoked concurrently with different batches without awaiting other batches' completion. Note that the maximum number of messages is not the exact number of messages a batch will contain.

Comment: "Note that the maximum number of messages is not the exact number of messages a batch will contain." I am assuming this happens when the # of message remaining is less then the maxMessageCount. If not, then which setting tells the exact number of message in a batch?

Comment: Incorrect assumption. ASB will never send the exact number even if the batch size is less than the number of available messages. That's just how the service work. That's why the parameter is called `max` and not `count`.

Comment: In this example the author set maxMessageCount = 3 in batchOptions. He is able to verify that he received 3 messages at one time: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/consume-batch-messages-azure-function-from-service-bus-dimitar-iliev

Comment: Another question: Let say maxMessageCount = 5 and maxConcurrentCalls = 1. Is there any time interval between each batch got processed by default?

Comment: Sean is correct; there is no guarantee of a minimum batch size.  The client sets the max when asking the service to stream messages in.  The result is highly dependent on the network and the structure of the messages themselves.  You may receive anywhere from 0-Max, depending on what is available to the client at the time.   Setting a prefetchCount allows you to eagerly stream messages in and generally increases the average number of messages read for most workloads.  Messages held in prefetch are locked and there is no way to renew the lock, so you risk expired locks if not reading quickly.

Comment: @JesseSquire I think it is OK to receive 0-Max messages. I would like to learn more on the time between each batch got processed. Let say maxMessageCount = 5 and maxConcurrentCalls = 1. And there are a lot more active messages in the queue. Will the second batch trigger the function as soon as the function received the first batch? Is this time interval also dependent on the network and the structure of the messages?

Comment: Read/Dispatch is a tight loop, Once your Function invocation completes, the client will request the next batch.   As mentioned above, this process is independent for each degree of concurrency that you enable, though I cannot speak to how the Function host manages individual instances when the trigger asks it to deliver a batch.

Comment: @JesseSquire ok thanks. Is it possible to control the time interval within service bus trigger or is that something we need to use with timetrigger instead?

Comment: It is not possible to change behavior.  Service Bus trigger is intended to stream messages to the Function as they become available, not run on any specific schedule.

Comment: If there was a 3-in-1 badge, I'd give it to @JesseSquire 